# VSTS create git tag

Tags: bitbucket, azure-pipelines

I'm looking for a way to set a tag. I'm using a bitbucket git repository. I found the "Allow Git remote access" and "Restore Git remote" tasks which were created by Pascal Berger.

How ever it gives an error when performing a `git push`:

`fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://OAuth:***@bitbucket.org:443/MyCompany/MyRepo.git/'`

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **PowerShell task** to create and push a tag to your bitbucket git repo.

Detail steps as below (you can follow the situation you meet):

#### Situation 1: VSTS build defiition Get sources from the bitbucket repo

If the repo you want to push a tag is same as you specified in Get sources step, then you can **create and push the tag directly**. And the PowerShell script as below:

```
git tag <tag name>
git push https://username:password@bitbucket.org/account/repo.git --tags
```

[image]

**Note:**

- You need to provider credential in the remote repo URL.
- If you want to create an annotated tag, then use the command `git tag -a <tag name> -m 'message'` instead.
- If you want to create a tag on a history commit instead of creating tag on `HEAD`, then specify the history commit sha-1 value in git tag command. Such as `git tag v1.1 e313a7b`, or `git tag -a v1.1 e313a7b -m 'create v1.1 on commit e313a7b'`.

#### Situation 2: the tag you want to create to the bitbucket repo is different from what you specified in Get sources step

If the bitbucket repo you want to push tag is different from what you specified in Get sources step, then you need to **clone the bitbucket repo firstly, and then create and push tag to the bitbucket repo**. The PowerShell script as below:

```
git clone https://username:password@bitbucket.org/account/repo.git repo
cd repo
git tag  <tag name>
git push --tags
```